# Where is blocked/allowed URLs in content setting->notifications stored?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, web-push

There are list of URLs that are blocked/allowed in my chrome browser to receive or not receive notifications. Where are those urls stored? is there any db or some kind of storage for that? If so how can i access that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to access it programmatically or via the UI?

Comment: @t1gor: programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Notifications settings, you can find those under `chrome://settings/content/notifications`. Look under the tab "Advanced" -> "Notifications".